# Access to the base_path of a particular Asset directory from a controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I want to access the `base_path` (`base_url` registered) of a specific [Asset component](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component#configuration-changes) directory from a controller in order to store my reports to a specific path preconfigured in config.yml.

I started changing my configuration, after upgrading to **Symfony 2.7**, like the following:

<kbd>**app/config/config.yml**</kbd>

```
framework:
    assets:
        version: 'v5'
        version_format: '%%s?version=%%s'
        base_path: ~
        base_urls: ['http://cdn.example.com', 'https://secure.example.com']
        packages:
           reports:
             base_path: bundles/mybundle
```

So, when I request a specific route, with the correct *request parameters* my controller generate the HTML from a particular Twig template and, at the end, it will be converted to PDF using [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle).

At last, my purpose is to build a list of generated PDF reports accessible from a public assets directory.

#### $kernel->locateResource()

However, I can access the complete path using a workaround like the following:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@MyBundle/Resources/public/reports')
```

#### Using parameters.yml

I have also asked for some hints and it seems legit to use the `parameters.yml` in order to manage the *Asset component* configuration. So, from the controller, they would be accessed using `$this->getParameter()` and, at the same time, as a configuration value for Asset.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but what exactly is your question? Can you make it stand out a bit more?

Comment: I need to access (from a controller) the `base_urls` defined in **app/config/config.yml**, and I want to do it directly.
Something like `getAssets('base_urls')`.

Comment: Yes but you also provide some solutions, are they not working or are you asking about what is the best one? I assumed the latter in my answer.

Comment: They work but I think it's better to have a way to access to the config.yml configuration of the `assets` section. If you define different sub-paths makes sense to retrieve them directly without defining in two distinct yml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with that is to define it as a parameter in `parameters.yml`, as you suggested yourself.

It's really easy to get it and it totally makes sense.

*Update*

I wanted to provide a bit more reasoning for my answer, so I will cite http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html as a reference.

Reading there, it seems that you should put into "parameters.yml" all infrastructure parameters which do not really change your application behaviours. I think this applies to your case as well: your application does not change its behaviour according to assets paths, it only needs to know where they are.

So, again, I'd say that putting them in parameters.yml not only provides you an easy solution but also it's a "good practice".

Comment: As I stated in the previos comments, I would like to have a method to access the `assets` paths configurations from the controller actions, without the need of defining them in the parameters.yml.

Comment: Ok. I understand and respect your question so I cannot provide a solution. Anyway I extended my answer with a little more evidence :-)

Comment: Thank you for the update and the clarification. Right now I'm using the parameters.yml method.